# React Redux draft.js - Validation upon empty textarea results in weird cursor positioning

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, draftjs

I'm currently using [DraftJS](https://draftjs.org/docs/overview.html#content) in a React project of mine and I've been stuck in a spot with a custom component I created where I'm utilizing draftjs in addition to some redux validation.

The problem is that, I have the validation working where if the user is typing, then deletes all of the text from the textarea, is prompts the redux validation and a "Required" text shows up, however due to some code I have, I'm running into this weird issue with the cursor highlighting a single letter or being pushed to the first position of the textarea when I press backspace/delete and it's causing my textarea to be unusable.

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { RadioButton, RadioButtonGroup } from 'material-ui/RadioButton';
import { Editor, EditorState, convertFromRaw } from 'draft-js';

class TextareaRequired extends React.Component {  react/prefer-stateless-function


    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.input.value === '') {
            if (this.props.data) {
                this.props.input.onChange(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(this.props.data))));
            }
        }
    }

    changeTextArea(editorState) {
        if (this.props.input.onChange) {
            this.props.input.onChange(editorState);
        }
        // If the editorState is empty; we change the input value to null to enable invalid state for redux
        if (!editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText()) {
            this.props.input.onChange(null);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { meta } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="grey-border">
                <Editor
                    editorState={this.props.input.value || EditorState.createEmpty()}
                    onChange={::this.changeTextArea} // eslint-disable-line
                />
              </div>
                {meta.touched && meta.error && <div className="form-error">{meta.error}</div>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TextareaRequired;
```

In my `changeTextArea()` function, I believe the issue has something to do with this snippet here, though I have no reason why:

```
if (!editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText()) {
   this.props.input.onChange(null);
}
```

Has anyone used Draft.js enough to know what the potential issue here is?

Thanks in advance